# Why is the API data not displayed on the front side in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, asynchronous, frontend

I'm creating a fullstack app in Angular and SpringBoot. I have already did this type of projects many time before, but I have a simple problem that I can't solve.

Here the .ts file :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ChestService } from '../chest.service';
import { Chest } from '../chest.model';
import { lastValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chest',
  templateUrl: './chest.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chest.component.scss']
})
export class ChestComponent implements OnInit {

  chests: Chest[] = [];

  constructor(private chestService: ChestService) {

  }

  async ngOnInit() {
    await this.getAllChests();
    console.log(this.chests)
  }

  async getAllChests() {
    const data = await lastValueFrom(this.chestService.getAllChests());
    this.chests = data;
  }
}
```

Here the .html file :

```
<h1>Mes coffres</h1>
<ng-container *ngIf="chests && chests.length > 0">
  <div *ngFor="let chest of chests">
      <p>{{ chest.name }}</p>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

and the model :

```
export class Chest {
    id ?: number;
    name ?: string;
    description ?: string;
    creationDate ?: string;
    username ?: string;
    password ?: string;
    link ?: string;
  
    constructor(id ?: number, name ?: string, description ?: string, creationDate ?: string, username ?: string, password ?: string, link ?: string) {
      this.id = id;
      this.name = name;
      this.description = description;
      this.creationDate = creationDate;
      this.username = username;
      this.password = password;
      this.link = link;
    }
  }
```

When I consult the network tab of the browser, I notice that the objects are transmitted from the api. In the .ts file, console.log(this.chests) displays the objects in the console. But the ;html file only displays the  tag, and I don't understand why it doesn't displays the name of every object.

Does anyone know what's the problem ?

Comment: Can you just try by adding `<pre>{{ chests | json }}</pre>` in html and can you see the JSON?

Comment: @AshishMishra yes I can see the JSON with the good values ! but I don't understand why I can't display them differently

Comment: @EricPhillips this is the first time I get async problems

Comment: Do you have a shareable link to your code

Comment: What happens if you avoid those asyncs, like:

`ngOnInit() {
    this.chestService.getAllChests().subscribe(chests => {
   this.chests = chests})
  }`

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved : the field names for backend objet weren't the same as field names for frontend object.